# Is Whimsyshire worth the cost at inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Whimsyshire drop better loot than other areas?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70921/does-whimsyshire-drop-better-loot-than-other-areas)

I want to know if spending money on upgrading the staff of herding all the way up to inferno is worth it, is the loot good enough to warrant upgrading my staff?

**Update**
Also, how hard is it? I currently can't get past Act 2, but I got the plans with a bug I've found (you start any quest in Hell, go to Public Games, and you are given the option to join that same quest but in inferno, even if you haven't cleared the previous acts.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Whimsyshire drop better loot than other areas?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70921/does-whimsyshire-drop-better-loot-than-other-areas) See also: [How much gold will you make on average for a Hell/Inferno Whimsyshire run?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71211/how-much-gold-will-you-make-on-average-for-a-hell-inferno-whimsyshire-run)

Comment: Hi Nico, we try to keep it to one question per... question, but your edit is answered by the existing question, [How difficulty is Whimsyshire?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70907/how-difficult-is-whimsyshire)